# What is this sound? Some kind of LFO synth? Song: Heart of a Lion, Kid Cudi

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, sound, synthesizer, synthesis

I am wanting to create a sound like this one. It has something to do with LFOs with a degree of instability.

[Shows itself at 0:25-0:30 as it rises in pitch and does so again a few times throughout such as 1:25 and 3:00]

There is also a similar sound in Lana Del Rey-Born To Die

at 1:30 and 1:40 (and at times throughout)

Whatever the technique is for creating this type of sound, it was used on both of these tracks of course in their own altered ways.

If anybody knows exactly what this is help me out and share with me. Thank you.
<3

Comment: I'd say there's an lfo attached to the pitch, as well as a ring mod. The ring mod is especially obvious on the first one, and the lfo is stronger on the second.

Answer (score 1):

long story short, experiment with the lfo on the pitch, and the volume, im not in front of my daw at the moment. but thats a good place to start. Also it sounds as though some of those sounds have a bit crusher over the top of it at some points. which is the high end distortion.